# Usages de « au-delà (de) » et « par delà (de) »

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu

D'après le Wiktionnaire :

> [au-delà](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/au-del%C3%A0) adverbe de lieu
>   1. Plus loin que.
>   2. Indique ce qui dépasse un seuil.
>
> [par-delà](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/par-del%C3%A0) locution prépositive
>   1. Plus loin que ; de l’autre côté de. — Note : Se dit au propre et au figuré.

Quelles sont les différences d'usage ?

Pourquoi est-ce que le Wiktionnaire ne montre pas « par-delà de » ?

De la [page 353](http://books.google.com/books?id=F0rc4PGi2V0C&pg=PA353&dq=%22par-dela+de%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=gWPwUqvmL8ahkQX_loDICw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22par-dela%20de%22&f=false) des *Œuvres complètes*, volumes 5 et 6 par Charles Pinot-Duclos :

> Monsieur du Bouchage, nous n’avons point de trêve par deçà, par quoi il me faut aider des gens d'armes ; et pour ce je vous prie que vous en veniez le plutôt que vous pourrez, et les gens d’armes par deçà, et les gens de monsieur du Lude et de Gonsoles en Guyenne ; et s'il n’y avoit assez de gens **par delà de** ceux de Bouffile, pour tenir la chose en sûreté, laissez-y ceux de Gonsoles, et se Gonsoles n’y veut demeurer, envoyez-le moi, et lui dites que je lui donnerai de l'argent…

Comment: I've seen this in almost all of your questions, and I think most have been edited, but I'll point this mistake so you can learn. "*La suite*" in this context is not the right translation to "the following". A much more idiomatic way to say it would be "*ce qui suit* + present". When you say "*la suite*", it really means more something like "the sequel" or "the continuation" of something like a two-parter TV episode.

Comment: @Kareen: Merci beaucoup. Je ne le savais pas. Je suis désolé à tous qui étaient accablés. Prière de ne pas hésiter à m'aviser des erreurs sur-le-champ.

Answer (score 1):

Pas de référence à donner mais l'usage (courant) est :

- *au-delà **de [quelque chose]***
- *par-delà **un/le [mot ou groupe nominal]***

et non « *au-delà la montagne* » ou « *par-delà du bois* ».

Dans le texte donné en exemple (du 18<sup>e</sup> siècle), il s'agit probablement d'une tournure qui existait à l'époque et n'est plus utilisée aujourd'hui.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Euh, merci... je serai plus propre la prochaine fois si c'est important.

Answer (score 0):

Curieusement le Littré donne une définition pour *au delà* mais pas pour *par-delà*, alors qu'il fournit une citation où se trouve ces deux locutions :

> **. . . . .**
>   2°  Loc. prépos. ♦ Ma maison qui a le lac en miroir au bout
>   du jardin, et la Savoie **par delà ce** lac, et les Alpes **au delà
>   de** cette Savoie, VOLT., Lettr. d'Argental, 8 janvier, 1758 
>   **. . . . .**

Sinon la définition d'une séparation, d'une limite, induit *au-delà de*, *par-delà* est une virtualisation ou une évocation d'un espace lointain.